# Can I check Userlogin Username and Password with a REST Service in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, json, rest, xamarin

hi i build a xamarin android application and have three activities for a loginsystemn.

I want to use a REST Service for checking the Username and Password.

What is the best way to check username and password in a mobile application and how make it? Can I use a REST Service for check the user data?

Answer (score 0):

Reference

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36460334/edit

**From above link**
A simple example:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("localhost:8080");

string jsonData = @"{""username"" : ""myusername"", ""password"" : ""mypassword""}"

var content = new StringContent (jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/foo/login", content);

// this result string should be something like: "{"token":"rgh2ghgdsfds"}"
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Where `"/foo/login"` will need to point to your HTTP resource.  For example, if you have an `AccountController` with a `Login` method, then instead of `"/foo/login"` you would use something like `"/Account/Login"`.

You can use post service to send username and password in `RequestBody` in json formate and get the response from server for the same.